# batch script for given extension type of files replication in a drive with different file name

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to batch scripting,

I want a script for performing below job!
In a drive like (C,D or E) search for all .txt files and want the same copy in the same location with different name like .txt_backup07082014.

In any location in entire drive it finds the .txt file, script should replicate the file as is except the change in file name.

Lets assume the below folder structure before execution of scripts

C (Drive)--

```
       Test (Folder)--
                    TestResults.txt
                    TestCases.txt
                    TestExecution.txt
        Dev (Folder)--
                    DevCodeFiles.txt
                    Configurations.txt
                    ToolsUsed.txt

       Automation (Folder)-- 
                       Sample.txt
             Sanity (Folder)-- <<<This folder is subfolder for Automation>>>
                            Scripts.txt
```

I'm looking for the solution like below after execution of scripts

C (Drive)--

```
       Test (Folder)--
                    TestResults.txt
                    TestResults.txt_07082014
                    TestCases.txt
                    TestCases.txt_07082014
                    TestExecution.txt
                    TestExecution.txt_07082014
        Dev (Folder)--
                    DevCodeFiles.txt
                    DevCodeFiles.txt_07082014
                    Configurations.txt
                    Configurations.txt_07082014
                    ToolsUsed.txt
                    ToolsUsed.txt_07082014

       Automation (Folder)-- 
                       Sample.txt
                       Sample.txt_07082014
             Sanity (Folder)-- <<<This folder is subfolder for Automation>>>
                            Scripts.txt
                            Scripts.txt_07082014
```

Comment: searching for files through entire drive could take hours. May be you should consider a set of directories you want to check.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I agree the time line will be more, but requirement is like that.

Comment: If you haven't got a solution yet then give some more examples of what you need to do.  If there are two files in a folder then how do you want them renamed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it: change `c:\` to the drive you want to process.  Test it on sample files first.

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%"

for /r "c:\" %%a in (*.txt) do copy "%%a" "%%a_%datestamp%"
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the `pushd f:\` to the drive you need:

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd f:\
@echo off
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do set "current_date=%%c%%b%%e" && del ~.*

set current_date=%current_date:Jan=01%
set current_date=%current_date:Feb=02%
set current_date=%current_date:Mar=03%
set current_date=%current_date:Apr=04%
set current_date=%current_date:May=05%
set current_date=%current_date:Jun=06%
set current_date=%current_date:Jul=07%
set current_date=%current_date:Aug=08%
set current_date=%current_date:Sep=09%
set current_date=%current_date:Oct=10%
set current_date=%current_date:Nov=11%
set current_date=%current_date:Dec=12%



for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%f in ('dir /s /b /r /a:-d *.txt') do (
    copy /y "%%~f" "%%~f_%current_date%"
)

popd
endlocal
```